# Add class to custom autodivider Return statement

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile-listview

I am working on a custom autodivider to divide the posts based on post date and also include the comment counts in the divider header. The posts are currently been divided by the date it was posted and also I have the comment counts included but the issue I am facing is I want the comment bit to be set to float to the right while the date stays on left.

Below is the code I have come up with:

```
$('#postlist').listview({
  autodividers: true,
  autodividersSelector: function (li) {
    var out = li.find("p").map(function() {return $(this).text();});
    var datedivider = out.get(2);
    var countdivider = out.get(3);
  return [datedivider, countdivider];
 }
});
```

Output: The red line is the comment count and below it is the console.log
[image]

How do I add a class or id to the return statement so i can style it or is there a better way to add comment count on listdivider header.

HTML:

```
<div id="sbpage" data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b" class="css-dd-header">
            <p class="css-dd-text">Latest Article</p>
            <a href="#home" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext" data-direction="reverse" data-transition="flow">Home</a>
            <a href="" data-icon="search" class="css-search" data-iconpos="notext" data-direction="reverse">Search</a>
        </div><!-- header -->
        <div data-role="content">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="d" id="postlist" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Filter posts..."  data-autodividers="true" data-icon="false"> </ul><!-- content -->
        </div>
    </div><!-- page -->
```

Comment: wrap the count with a `span` with a specific class (`01 November, 2013,<span class="count">0</span`) and then add css to style however you want.

Comment: @Krishna Yes I know I need a span but where can I add this. Thanks

Comment: You might need to edit the text of the `li` on the fly using javascript on DOM ready.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use jquery-mobile formatted content http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/widgets/listviews/#list-formatted

So you could enter something like,

```
<li data-role="list-divider">Friday, October 8, 2010 <span class="ui-li-count">2</span></li>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eH4gq/

and if you need to further style it, you can simply use css and select its class value.

You need to remove `data-autodividers="true"` and enter it as follows,

```
<ul data-role="listview" 
    data-theme="d" 
    id="postlist" 
    data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Filter posts..."   data-icon="false">
    <li data-role="list-divider">Friday, October 8, 2010 <span class="ui-li-count">2</span></li><!--content-->....
```

**EDIT**

In order to do this dynamically with a custom autodivider, since the `ui-li-count` does not seem to be handled by `autodividersSelector` *(as far as i can see in jqm code)* , you could wrap the part of content you require in a `span` element as others have suggested. One way to achieve this would be to call `trigger` on a custom event after refreshing the listview and modify the contents of each generated divider. In the code that follows you will notice that a special token has been used to split the parts of the divider's text. For example,

http://jsfiddle.net/45Zwu/

**js**

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#test", function () {

    $('#postlist').on("afterRefresh", function () {
        $(".ui-li-divider").each(function(){
            console.log($(this).text());
            var textSplit = $(this).text().split(",_#_");
            var countValue = textSplit[1];
            $(this).text(textSplit[0]);

            var count = document.createElement('span');
            $(count).addClass('comments-count').text(countValue);
            $(this).append(count);
        });
    });

    $('#postlist').listview({
        autodividers: true,
        autodividersSelector: function (li) {
            var out = li.text().substring(0, 1);
            var ranomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1;
            return [out, "_#_"+ranomNumber];
        }
    }).listview("refresh").trigger("afterRefresh");

});
```

**html**

```
<div id="test" data-role="page" data-theme="c">
    <div data-role="header">
         <h1>test</h1>

    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul id="postlist" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-autodividers="true">
            <li><a href="index.html">Adam Kinkaid</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Alex Wickerham</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Avery Johnson</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Bob Cabot</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Caleb Booth</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Christopher Adams</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Culver James</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.comments-count{
    float:right;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @melc, I have included my HTML code. How do I integrate your answer. Please note this is a custom autodivider. Thanks

Comment: sorry the divider list is dynamic, so this is not hard coded but fetch from the server. That's why I mentioned that this is a custom autodivider.

Comment: @Chelseawillrecover i see what you mean, just updated the answer, as a response to your comments.